# Java ошибка при запуске jar

Tags: java, hibernate

Скачал java программу (больше не поддерживается). К программе шла иструкция, где было написано, что для работы нужно уставновить `jdk-13_windows-x64_bin.exe` и `jre-8u221-windows-x64.exe`, и запустить командой `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -server -jar server.jar`

Я все это сделал и у меня появилась ошибка, я её быстро исправил переустановив java.

Дальше я столкнулся с такой ошибкой. Я не знаю, что не хватает системе, чтобы этой ошибки не было. Как я понял, что эта ошибка связана с возможностью подключиться к mysql.

Вряд-ли это баг в программе, т.к. есть видео с демонстрацией работы, где всё нормально. Я всё повторил по видео.

С чем может быть связана ошибка?

```
ERROR util.XMLHelper: Error parsing XML: hibernate.cfg.xml(1) The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at gtanks.services.hibernate.HibernateService.<clinit>(HibernateService.java:13)
    at gtanks.main.Main.main(Main.java:50)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
    at gtanks.services.hibernate.HibernateService.<clinit>(HibernateService.java:11)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd : The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. Nested exception: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1484)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в библиотеке, которая загружала файл http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd в неверной кодировке. Ошибку исправили и всё само заработало